# d3 mouse events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I am having trouble triggering d3 events on mousedown, mouseup and mousemove. The code does not work when I move it to the production server (otherwise it works fine with a simple index.html and only a jquery and d3 libraries). On the production folder, there are other libraries for draggable elements that do not have anything to do with the svg and d3 implementation I am trying to get done here. I am just thinking they could be possible causes for a conflict with the mouse events: (Any help would be appreciated)

Here us my code (which works fine outside of the production environment): I am trying to draw a line on mouse move:

```
    var container  = d3.select('svg');

    function draw(selection){
        var xy0, 
            path, 
            keep = false, 
            line = d3.svg.line()
                     .x(function(d){ return d[0]; })
                     .y(function(d){ return d[1]; });
        selection
            .on('mousedown', function(){      

            console.log("100")  

              console.log('THIS', this)
                keep = true;                     
                xy0 = d3.mouse(this);
                console.log('xy0', xy0)
                path = d3.select('svg')
                         .append('path')
                         .attr('d', line([xy0, xy0]))
                         .style({'stroke': 'red', 'stroke-width': '3px'});

                         console.log(path)


            })
            .on('mouseup', function(){ 
                var xUp = d3.mouse(this);

                console.log('xUp', xUp)

                keep = false; 
            })
            .on('mousemove', function(){ 
                if (keep) {
                    Line = line([xy0, d3.mouse(this)
                                .map(function(x){ return x - 1; })]);
                    console.log(Line);
                    path.attr('d', Line);
                }

                var xMove = d3.mouse(this);

                    console.log('x', xMove[0]);
                    console.log('y', xMove[1]);

                console.log('xMove', xMove)
            });
    }

 d3.select('svg').call(draw);
```

And here is the HTML

```
            <image xlink:href="dot.svg" x="7%" y="35%" height="20px" width="20px"></image>
             <image xlink:href="dot.svg" x="36%" y="35%" height="20px" width="20px"></image>
            <image  xlink:href="dot.svg" x="65%" y="35%" height="20px" width="20px"></image>


            <image xlink:href="dot.svg" x="7%" y="70%" height="20px" width="20px"></image>
             <image xlink:href="dot.svg" x="36%" y="70%" height="20px" width="20px"></image>
            <image  xlink:href="dot.svg" x="65%" y="70%" height="20px" width="20px"></image>

         </svg>
```

Comment: Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Answer (score -1):

Resolved. There was a draggable component in the same view, which when removed had the above problem go away. Which left me thinking, a conflict can arise between d3's and jQuery's mouse events.